# how to import discord bot object for use in other module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, discord, discord.py

I am trying to reduce the amount of lines in the main file of my discord bot, so i created a module to handle certain commands, the problem is i have to pass the bot object to every function outside the main file in the module, this increase the number of variables that i have pass to each function and its getting really confusing.

In the example Below, KsBot.py is my main bot file and BasicCommand.py is where i write my simple commands and import it to KsBot.py to use, KsBot is the bot object

In KsBot.py:

```
if message.content.startswith("//ping"):
    await BasicCommand.ping(KsBot,message.channel)
```

In BasicCommand.py:

```
async def ping(bot,channel):
    KsBot = bot
    await KsBot.send_message(channel,"pong")
```

I would like to add a variable in BasicCommand.py to represent KsBot so i don't have to pass in the bot object in every function, i've tried importing the bot object itself into BasicCommand.py by adding this to the top of the code:

```
from KsBot import KsBot
```

But it give me an error saying:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'KsBot'

Could someone explain to me why this error happens and if there is any way to pass this bot object. I am new to programming and discord.py so any alternative suggestions are appreciated as well , thank you :D

Comment: It might have something to do with only being able to import modules and class definitions instead of actual variables. Maybe you could define a `setup(bot)` that runs `global KsBot; KsBot = bot` and that you run once before your `KsBot.run()` call, not sure how well it'd work, but it might help

Comment: @LegacyKS can you post a base structure of KsBot.py (ie. definition of the bot + when you run the bot) and the file structure? In general, discord.py has an option to "add_extension" to an external file.

Comment: @squaswin Thank you for ur suggestion, it works great but if possible i would still like to pass the bot object without a function as i might be making more modules in the future. I will use this while i wait and see if there is any better alternatives :)

Comment: @abccd Hi, thank u for ur response, i m still new to this programming thing and have no idea  what u're talking bout but here is my whole file on github, i hope dat helps :D

File: https://github.com/legacyks/KsBot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good discord.py bot doesn't manually call all of the commands from `on_message`, you should use `@bot.command(pass_context=True)` to add a command.

Get rid of `def on_message(...):` since you're not doing anything meaningful in there.

Rough structure in one file (without splitting):

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('//')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_message(channel, "pong")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

It's that easy!

---

Now, multiple split into multiple files, the easiest method is to define your own `builtins.bot`. Alternatively, you can look into the `bot.load_extension("filename")` with a `def setup(bot):` in the second file. Both are valid methods, but the latter works best with cogs.

The following example is for the first method:

```
# ksbot.py
from discord.ext import commands
import builtins

bot = commands.Bot('//')
builtins.bot = bot

import basiccommand

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_message(channel, "pong")

bot.run("TOKEN")


# basiccommand.py

from discord.ext import commands
from builtins import bot

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    await bot.send_message(channel, "hi")
```

Now you have two commands, ping, which sends "pong", and hello, which sends "hi".

If have *have to* add a `on_message` handle, be sure to add `bot.process_commands(message)` at the end of `on_message`, the examples above does not require you to have the event handle.

Side note: for convention, filenames should be lowercased.

Comment: ah thank u so much for all the suggestion, tips and advices, i will try it as soon as i can make some time and let u know wat i think :D

Comment: first method still give the same error whereby it says ImportError: cannot import name 'KsBot'

Comment: @LegacyKS What's your code? If you followed the structure of my code, it will work, as you can see, I'm not doing a circular import.

Comment: right now, dis is wat i have: https://imgur.com/a/8Ji01sq

im still trying out the first method so this is the only 2 file i have.

Comment: @LegacyKS the `builtins.bot = bot` part in the first script needs to be above the import statement to to your second file. See the example I provided.